# Map between two direct limits

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $\{ M_i, ϕ_j^i\}_{i\in I}$ be a direct system of $R$-modules over a direct index set $I$. Show that there exists a direct system $\{P_i,\psi_j^i\}_{i\in I}$ of projective $R$-modules and a morphism $ t:\{P_i,\psi_j^i\}_{i\in I}\to \{M_i, ϕ_j^i\}_{i\in I}$ of directed systems such that:

(i) $t_i:P_i\to M_i $ is surjective  for all $i\in I$.

(ii) $ \underrightarrow{\lim}P_i$ is a projective $R$-module.

Who can help me to solve this problem ? I know what I want to prove but I can't write exactly. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this. First, you guarantee (1), so you find projective modules $P_i$'s for each $M_i$ so that there exist maps $t_i:P_i\rightarrow M_i$. Then let $Q_i=\oplus_{i\leq j} P_j$, and take $s_i=(\varphi^i_j\circ t_j)$. Then $Q_i$ are projective, there direct limit is projective (we set $\psi_j^i$ to be the natural injections), and the $s_i$ are surjective maps from $Q_i$ to $M_i$.